# Profiling / debugging API for VBA?

Tags: vba, profiling, porting

I am currently involved in porting a large and complicated VBA application to .NET 4.0.

In .NET I have access to the [Profiling API](http://www.blong.com/Conferences/DCon2003/Internals/Profiling.htm), which I have used to instrument an assembly to extract information about when classes are constructed, methods called, etc.

Is there an equivalent for VBA?  That is, some sort of callback system so I can write code which will be notified of events within VBA code as it executes?  I've spent some time on Google and contacted several VBA gurus, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921543/free-vb6-vba-profiler-and-best-excel-practices) didn't turn up much except a suggestion for a trial version.

[This profiler](http://www.bandwood.com/vbacp.htm) looks free and still available.

You could also search for [VB6 Profilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442052/vb6-profiler) which should also do the job.